# rows processed statistics information in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, statistics, dmv

In Oracle, there's a view called V$SQLAREA that lists statistics on shared SQL area and contains one row per SQL string. It provides statistics on SQL statements that are in memory, parsed, and ready for execution.

There is one column -ROWS_PROCESSED that sums the Total number of rows processed on behalf of this SQL statement.

I'm looking for collateral information in SQLSERVER 2005.

I looked in some of the DMV's (like sys.dm_exec_query_stats), but I haven't found anything related.

@@ROWCOUNT won't be useful to me, as I want incremental statistics information that will sum the rows_processed of the top cpu/io/execution consumption queries in the database.

I would appreciate any help in regards the subject.

Thanks in advance,

Roni.

---

I saw that when I query the following query, I receive the Query Plan in XML.

Inside the XML plan code, there's a "EstimateRows" part with a number that correlates to the number of estimation rows of the query.

I'm thinking of the option to substr the query_plan column to retreive only the above information (unless I would find it in some system views/tables).

**Where can I find the Actual number of rows of the query ? Where is it stored ?**

```
SELECT 
       case when sql_handle IS NULL
           then ' '
           else ( substring(st.text,(statement_start_offset+2)/2,       
   (case when qs.statement_end_offset = -1         
   then len(convert(nvarchar(MAX),st.text))*2      
   else statement_end_offset    
   end - statement_start_offset) /2  ) )
        end as query_text , 
    query_plan,
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle)
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) st;
```

Comment: I can't see a good reason for wanting that information?

Comment: To see if a specific row returns large amount of rows, then we can analyze the applicative queries - perhaps the WHERE clause is too broad..

Comment: We use this information frequently in our Oracle analysis (Our application supports Oracle & SQL SERVER), and we would like to know if there's an equivalent information (statistics) in the system views/tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent especially for rowcounts as far as I know. The relevant dmvs track IO cost which is used to show missing indexed, most expensive queries etc

This will give you stats per SQL statement for current sessions. YMMV: I've just put it together based on scripts I have lying around.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats  QS
    CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) ST
```

My scripts are based on the links I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118156/what-are-the-first-issues-to-check-while-optimizing-an-existing-database/4119107#4119107)

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response, however, I already have a general queries that retrieve the statistics information you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system variable @@rowcount to know the number of records affected by last statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but didn't you read my question ?

@@ROWCOUNT won't be useful to me, as I want incremental statistics information that will sum the rows_processed of the top cpu/io/execution consumption queries in the database.